# Limitar aggregation por item agrupado no mongo

Tags: ruby, mongodb

Tenho uma coleção composta da seguinte forma, só que com muito mais dados.

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("db759d014f70743495ef1000"),
  tracked_item_origin: "winword",
  tracked_item_type: "Software",
  machine_user: "mmm.mmm",
  organization_id: ObjectId("a91864df4f7074b33b020000"),
  group_id: ObjectId("20ea74df4f7074b33b520000"),
  tracked_item_id: ObjectId("1a050df94f70748419140000"),
  tracked_item_name: "Word",
  duration: 9540,
}

{
  _id: ObjectId("2b769d014f70743495fa1000"),
  tracked_item_origin: "http://www.facebook.com",
  tracked_item_type: "Site",
  machine_user: "gabriel.mello",
  organization_id: ObjectId("a91864df4f7074b33b020000"),
  group_id: ObjectId("3f6a64df4f7074b33b040000"),
  tracked_item_id: ObjectId("6f3466df4f7074b33b080000"),
  tracked_item_name: "Facebook",
  duration: 7920,
}
```

Já fiz um aggregation que me retorna de forma agrupada todos estes dados da seguinte forma:

```
{"_id"=>{"tracked_item_type"=>"Site", "tracked_item_name"=>"Twitter"}, "duration"=>288540},
{"_id"=>{"tracked_item_type"=>"Site", "tracked_item_name"=>"ANoticia"}, "duration"=>237300},
{"_id"=>{"tracked_item_type"=>"Site", "tracked_item_name"=>"Facebook"}, "duration"=>203460},
{"_id"=>{"tracked_item_type"=>"Software", "tracked_item_name"=>"Word"}, "duration"=>269760},
{"_id"=>{"tracked_item_type"=>"Software", "tracked_item_name"=>"Excel"}, "duration"=>204240}
```

O código da agregation é simples:

```
AgentCollector.collection.aggregate(
  {'$match' => {group_id: '20ea74df4f7074b33b520000'}},
  {'$group' => {
    _id: {tracked_item_type: '$tracked_item_type', tracked_item_name: '$tracked_item_name'},
    duration: {'$sum' => '$duration'}
  }},
  {'$sort' => {
    '_id.tracked_item_type' => 1,
    duration: -1
  }}
)
```

Meu problema, é como eu posso limitar a somente 2 items agrupados de Site (tracked_item_type: "Site") e 2 items de Software (tracked_item_type: "Software")?

Answer (score 1):

Pensei muito em uma maneira mais simples de fazer isso, mas aparentemente a única maneira possível é jogar o resultado dessa agregação em uma coleção e depois fazer os filtros em cima desse resultado armazenado.

**Guardando o resultado do relatório em uma nova collection**: O comando "aggregate" não tem esse tipo de opção, para isso posso substituir por um mapReduce() que fará a mesma coisa porém especificando a opção "out":

```
db.trackeditems.mapReduce(
  function() {
      var key = {'tracked_item_type': this.tracked_item_type, 'tracked_item_name': this.tracked_item_name};
      emit(key, this.duration);
  },
  function(key, values) { 
      var totalDuration = 0; 
      for (var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) { 
          totalDuration += values[i] 
      } 
      return totalDuration;
  },
  {
     out: "tracked_items_report",
     query: {group_id: ObjectId('20ea74df4f7074b33b520000')}
  }
)
```

Obs: Não tenho conhecimento da API em Ruby, por isso estou mostrando o exemplo apenas na linha de comando no Mongo.

**Consultando o relatório**

Depois de executar esse comando você terá em seu db a coleção tracked_items_report com o resultado da agregação. A partir daí pode fazer qualquer query ordenando e limitando os registros de modo a conseguir o resultado desejado.

```
// Obtendo os 2 tops no tipo 'Site'
db.tracked_items_report.find({'_id.tracked_item_type': 'Site'}).sort({'value':-1}).limit(2)
// Obtendo os 2 tops no tipo 'Software'
db.tracked_items_report.find({'_id.tracked_item_type': 'Software'}).sort({'value':-1}).limit(2)
```

Sim, dá um pouco mais de trabalho, agora são 3 operações no banco ao invés de apenas uma (que de acordo com sua pergunta seria o ideal), mas você também ganha "de graça" um benefício adicional que é ter o resultado da agregação (possivelmente uma transação pesada) guardado em banco como um cache para consultas posteriores.